# Close ports 8080 and 8443 for wildfl 14

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04

I deployed wildfly 14 & Nginx on a pre-prodction server.Where Nginx is a reverse proxy. and I forced wildfly to use the ssl throught the 443 by adding a socket-binding

```
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public">
      ...
      <socket-binding name="https-external" port="443"/>
      ...
```

and I modified the http-listener

```
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
```

when I scan the server for the opened ports I found this result:

```
80/tcp   open     http
443/tcp  open     https
445/tcp  filtered microsoft-ds
8080/tcp open     http-proxy
8443/tcp open     https-alt
```

so how can I stop wildfly from listening on 8080 and 8443 whiout causing any damage and keeping the admin console accessible?

Comment: Are you sure that nginx is not listening on 443? If it does, then Wildfly will try to bind on the defined port (443 in your case) and if the port is in use, I suppose it will bind to 8443. No idea how wildfly works or behaves but from my little experience with Java Apps, that might be a common scenario

Comment: run this as root to find out which processes are binding to which ports: `netstat -ntlpe`, paste the output here so that we can be sure what to answer.

Comment: this is the result of netstat -tulpn
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9990          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2303/java           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2303/java       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1460/nginx -g daemo
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2303/java       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1460/nginx -g daemo

Comment: Ok, so you see the output? There's a java process binding on all interfaces `0.0.0.0:8080 && 0.0.0.0:8443`, which I suppose is the mentioned wildfly. You should instruct wildfly to bind only to the loopback device, and then have the reverse proxy bind on the loopback, and only letting nginx to bind to the public interface.

Comment: that's right the java process are those of the wildfly , but how can instruct wildfly to listen to the loopback device ?

Comment: That young man, is an exercise for you to try at home, I never worked with wildfly before, but my guess is tweaking the attribute `default-interface` in the XML tag `socket-binding-group`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here it is:

https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/0f873236ffe8a0ea9dc78acbf3b18d4a59fbb98a/docs/src/main/asciidoc/_admin-guide/Interfaces_and_ports.adoc

This piece of documentation states there's a XML section like this:

```
<interfaces>
  <interface name="management">
   <inet-address value="127.0.0.1"/>
  </interface>
  <interface name="public">
   <inet-address value="127.0.0.1"/>
  </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Just look if inet-address for both public and management interfaces are set to the value above, and I think you'll have it working as expected.

Comment: Thnaks Marcel! you saved me!